# Vector Calculus proof bogus or not?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider an arbitrary vector real valued function smooth and continuous $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{r} = \| \mathbf{r} \|^2$

Given $ (\| \mathbf{r} \|^2)'  = (\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{r})' = \mathbf{r}' \cdot \mathbf{r} + \mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{r}' = 2\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{r}' = 0$

Does it follow that $\|\mathbf{r}\|$ is a constant because $(\| \mathbf{r} \|^2)' = 0$?

Comment: What is this prime supposed to represent?  Differentiation with respect to...what?

Comment: Any parameter. I left it out because I thought it may create confusion.

Comment: What does the "Then" mean? When the function $t\mapsto{\bf r}(t)$ is "arbitrary" then you cannot expect that $2{\bf r}\cdot{\bf r}'\equiv0$.

Comment: I suspect the word "Then" should be replaced with, say, "Given"?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter, are there times when it isn't true? What if I add the fact that $\mathbf{r}$ has constant speed? That is $\| \mathbf{r}' \| = \text{constant}$

Comment: Assume ${\bf a}\ne{\bf 0}$ and put ${\bf r}(t):=t\>{\bf a}$. Then ${\bf r}'(t)\equiv{\bf a}$ and $2{\bf r}\cdot{\bf r}'=2 t\|{\bf a}\|^2\ne0$ $\ (t\ne0)$.

Comment: Okay clearly I've mispoken. I will make the corrections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use
$$
f(t)=f(0)+\int_0^tf'(s)ds
$$
with $f(s)=\|r(s)\|^2$.

So yes, $\|r\|$ is constant if and only if $(\|r\|^2)'=0$.

If you do not want to integrate, use the mean value theorem:
$$
f(t)-f(0)=f'(s)(t-0)=f'(s)t
$$
for some $s$ between $0$ and $t$.

Comment: is there a proof where we can avoid integration? I want to do it soley in terms of vector products and derivatives.

Comment: Okay i can use MVT or integration, but what was wrong with my argument?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your argument. I just recalled why a smooth function is constant (on an interval) if and only if its derivative is zero...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I may have misread the question... **if** $\frac{d}{dt}\|r\|^2=0$ it follows that $\|r\|$ is constant. For arbitrary curves $r$ the former is not necessarily the case.

Yes. Let $f(t)$ be any differentiable scalar function with $\frac{d}{dt}(f^2) = 0$ on an interval $[a,b]$. By the chain rule, $2ff' = 0$, and $f$ is constant on every connected component where $f \neq 0$. It follows that $f$ must be constant on all of $[a,b]$.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but I wasn't sure if the same logic for scalar function will work on vector valued ones. Though to my previous knowledge, everything works exactly the same

Comment: Well, notice that in your case, $f(t) = \|r(t)\|$ is a scalar function.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct. The curve you depict is drawn in sphere. And since any radius and tangent of a sphere are perpendicular, the result you see with the dot product is no surprise.